# Mailchimp mc:hideable not working

Tags: html, html-email, mailchimp

I have coded one email template in Mailchimp account and they provide a template tag called **mc:hideable** that provides a feature to show/hide specific section on the page.

For testing purpose, I have created this simple code below

```
<div mc:hideable>Hello World!!</div>
```

When I move the mouse over the text, it shows me the Eye icon to show/hide it. But when I click it, nothing happens.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is the block only visible in the interface or is it hidden in the test you receive as well?

Comment: its always visible and when I click on the Hide button, nothing happens.

Comment: how about the test you receive? Is it hidden in the test or showing?

Answer (score 4):

They are not communicating it well, a flaw if you ask me.

In the **Template** (Edit Design/Edit Code) editor they only show you the symbol so you know which area's are "hideable". You can't interact with it as you may have noticed. It doesn't make sense to hide it, in that context.

However, when you create a **Campaign** using that Template you are able to fully interact with it, since you are actually composing the mail.

Hope this helps you and others interested.

Answer (score 2):

I've actually just encountered exactly the same yesterday. Had a break from working with mailchimp a couple of months, and getting back into it.

To get to the point: I've added some css-code to show the mc:hideable part properly, as this was also messed up somehow for me;

```
.tpl-hidewrap {
        left: 0 !important;
        right: 0 !important;
        display: block !important;
        height: 100px !important;
        text-align: center;
        z-index:3000;
    }
```

This was in case the clickable area (the eye) was hidden by the z-index or some other fault in the code. Still didn't work though.

Then I realised, I was trying to do all of this in the newly created *template* section...switched to the *campaign* section, made a new campaign with my new template, and there it does work. So code it, and test in a campaign!

Hope it's the same for you, and this works!

Comment: Thanks, I am going to give it a try.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and this didn't fix it for me

Comment: Had to test in campaign and not in the template editor/coder in order for `mc:hidable` to take affect